# Else part in Asynctask never gets executed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText movieText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.movieText);
    txt = movieText.getText().toString();
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new crawling().execute();

        }
    });
}

public class crawling extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String url ="http://www.filmibeat.com/movie_listings/Chennai.html";
    Document doc;
    Elements linksOnPage;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            linksOnPage = doc.select("a[href]");
        }
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        for(Element link : linksOnPage) {
            if (link.tagName("title").toString().contains(txt)) {
                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"YO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toast.cancel();
                    }
                },1000);

            }
            else{
                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"NO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toast.cancel();
                    }
                },1000);
            }
        }
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

**Whatever I give in the Edittext be it a string or nothing, I only get a "YO" toast. The else part never gets executed as the true second case. Why? Please help. Also, Am I parsing the link titles correctly?**

Comment: Print value of title and txt in Log , OR debug If() condition .

Comment: @Chetan Can you please explain? I've been breaking my head over this.

Comment: use a debugger and look at the value of `txt`.

Comment: write Log.e("txt value",txt); before if.and check its value in the console

Comment: there is no need to use handler to cancel the `Toast`

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 If i don't use a handler, I get a persistent toast which always stays on.

Answer (score 0):

Get input from EditText  onClick of Button before starting `AsyncTask` :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // get here text from EditText
           txt = movieText.getText().toString();
            new crawling().execute();

        }
```

Comment: Now, The if never gets executed and i'm getting a "NO" toast

Comment: @SaptharishiAnanthanarayanan: Probably `link.tagName("title").toString()` returning `""`